# Equation for integer exponents

Tags: equation-solving, exponent

I'm trying to solve some equations regarding power expansions, but Mathematica doesn't seem to find any solutions (it runs for an arbitrary long time). For example, I have the equation:

```
x1^-n[1, 1] (x1 - x2)^(-2 + n[1, 1] + n[1, 2] + n[1, 3]) x2^(
   1 - n[1, 2]) (x1 + x2)^-n[1, 3] sgn[1] + 
  x1^(1 - n[2, 1]) (x1 - x2)^(-2 + n[2, 1] + n[2, 2] + n[2, 3])
    x2^-n[2, 2] (x1 + x2)^-n[2, 3] sgn[2] == 0;
```

for integers `n[i,j]` and `sgn[i]` being either 0,1 or -1. For the second condition, I just add the equation `sgn[1]==Sign[sgn[1]]` and so on for `sgn[2]` and `sgn[3]`. I thought that Mathematica would have the least problems if I substituted `x1` and `x2` by random numerical values and repeated that enough times instead of leaving them as arbitrary variables, but neither `Solve` nor `Reduce` seem to do the job. However, I know that e.g.

```
{sgn[1]->1, sgn[2]->-1, sgn[3]->0, n[1,1]->0, n[1,2]->1, n[1,3]->1, n[2,1]->1, n[2,2]->0, n[2,3]->1}
```

is a valid solution for this equation. Is there a way to efficiently ask Mathematica so that it provided the general solution? Thanks in advance.

The code I'm using is:

```
signList = sgn /@ Range[4];
sgnEq = Table[sgn[ii] == Sign[sgn[ii]], {ii, Length@signList}];
powerList = Table[n[ii, jj], {ii,4}, {jj, 3}];
x2Num = {Rule[x1, RandomInteger[{10, 1000}]], Rule[x2, RandomInteger[{10, 1000}]]};
eqDep = Join[sgnEq, Table[entireEq /. x2Num, {jj, 100}] // Flatten];
sol = Reduce[eqDep, {signList, powerList} // Flatten, Integers];
```

where `entireEq` is just the first equation in my post.

Comment: Plugging your known solution into `EntireEq`, i.e., `EntireEq /. {sgn[1] -> 1, sgn[2] -> 2, sgn[3] -> 0, n[1, 1] -> 0, n[1, 2] -> 1, n[1, 3] -> 1, n[2, 1] -> 1, n[2, 2] -> 0, n[2, 3] -> 1}` evaluates to `3/(x1 + x2) == 0` rather than `True`. Something appears to be missing/incorrect.

Comment: @BobHanlon that's right, my mistake. `sgn[2]` should be -1, not 2. I've corrected the post.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

entireEq = 
  x1^-n[1, 1] (x1 - x2)^(-2 + n[1, 1] + n[1, 2] + n[1, 3]) x2^(1 - 
        n[1, 2]) (x1 + x2)^-n[1, 3] sgn[1] + 
    x1^(1 - n[2, 1]) (x1 - x2)^(-2 + n[2, 1] + n[2, 2] + n[2, 3]) x2^-n[2, 
        2] (x1 + x2)^-n[2, 3] sgn[2] == 0;

vars = {sgn[1], sgn[2], sgn[3], n[1, 1], n[1, 2], n[1, 3], n[2, 1], n[2, 2], 
   n[2, 3]};

sol = Thread[vars -> #] & /@ 
   Select[Tuples[{-1, 0, 1}, {9}], entireEq /. Thread[vars -> #] &];
```

Verifying all of the solutions,

```
And @@ (entireEq /. sol)

(* True *)
```

Number of solutions:

```
Length@sol

(* 2259 *)
```

First few examples

```
sol[[1 ;; 5]]

(* {{sgn[1] -> -1, sgn[2] -> 1, sgn[3] -> -1, n[1, 1] -> -1, n[1, 2] -> 0, 
  n[1, 3] -> -1, n[2, 1] -> 0, n[2, 2] -> -1, n[2, 3] -> -1}, {sgn[1] -> -1, 
  sgn[2] -> 1, sgn[3] -> -1, n[1, 1] -> -1, n[1, 2] -> 0, n[1, 3] -> 0, 
  n[2, 1] -> 0, n[2, 2] -> -1, n[2, 3] -> 0}, {sgn[1] -> -1, sgn[2] -> 1, 
  sgn[3] -> -1, n[1, 1] -> -1, n[1, 2] -> 0, n[1, 3] -> 1, n[2, 1] -> 0, 
  n[2, 2] -> -1, n[2, 3] -> 1}, {sgn[1] -> -1, sgn[2] -> 1, sgn[3] -> -1, 
  n[1, 1] -> -1, n[1, 2] -> 1, n[1, 3] -> -1, n[2, 1] -> 0, n[2, 2] -> 0, 
  n[2, 3] -> -1}, {sgn[1] -> -1, sgn[2] -> 1, sgn[3] -> -1, n[1, 1] -> -1, 
  n[1, 2] -> 1, n[1, 3] -> 0, n[2, 1] -> 0, n[2, 2] -> 0, n[2, 3] -> 0}} *)
```

Verifying that your known solution is in `sol`

```
MemberQ[sol, {sgn[1] -> 1, sgn[2] -> -1, sgn[3] -> 0, n[1, 1] -> 0, 
  n[1, 2] -> 1, n[1, 3] -> 1, n[2, 1] -> 1, n[2, 2] -> 0, n[2, 3] -> 1}]

(* True *)
```

Comment: That is very good! I can definitely use this to start with my problem. The only downside is that it has to go through the space of possible solutions. Do you know of a way that gives a general answer, meaning some of the `n[i,j]` in terms of the other ones?